# OSMnx has no attribute 'speed'

Tags: python, python-3.x, shortest-path, folium, osmnx

I've successfully downloaded the 0.14.0 version of osmnx:

[image]

But the output says AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'speed'.[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?
My python version is 3.8.1

Also, here are the code:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import os

ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

G = ox.graph_from_point((-33.889606, 151.283306), distance=3000, network_type='drive')

G = ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(G)
G = ox.speed.add_edge_travel_times(G)

orig = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (-33.889606, 151.283306))
dest = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (-33.862004, 151.211151))
route = nx.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, 'travel_time')

route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(G, route)
route_map.save('route_333.html')
```

Comment: Please, provide the output for `ox.__version__`. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh... It says 0.11
I thought I already installed the newest version. What should I do to update to the newest one?

Comment: Can you tell me what command to type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update OSMnx.

- using pip: `pip install -U osmnx`
- using conda: `conda update osmnx`

Then edit this line:

```
G = ox.graph_from_point((-33.889606, 151.283306), distance=3000, network_type='drive')
```

into:

```
G = ox.graph_from_point((-33.889606, 151.283306), dist=3000, network_type='drive')
```

and you get your map:

[image]

Comment: It says, ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
I've tried few methods I found on the Internet. But they all didn't help solving this problem.

Comment: What command have you run? Furthermore, what version of python are you using? Run `python --version`

Comment: The pip one, and my python version is 3.8.1\

Comment: Please, add the error you got to your question and the version of pip you are using. Thanks.

Comment: My pip version is pip 20.1.1 and the error is like ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Is that the full output?

Comment: If you continue to struggle to upgrade via pip, it may be easier to just reinstall the latest version of OSMnx following the [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) in the documentation. As @sentence mentioned, if you just upgrade to the latest version of the package, you will have access to the new `speed` module.

Comment: @sentence Hi, I've sent you the results via e-mail. Thanks for your passion.

Comment: @gboeing Should I uninstall OSMnx first then reinstall it? What command should I use? I accidentally input the wrong command. Now when I import osmnx on jupyter notebook, it says module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: I think you should consider the suggestion by @gboeing to uninstall the package (`pip uninstall osmnx`) and install it again. By the way, it seems that uninstalling rtree (`pip uninstall rtree`) should solve the problem as well.

Comment: @sentence Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.